# Return from .catch(error) not returning in Node / Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I'm writing a REST API and trying to correctly handle any errors.

When the API call succeeds, the the success object is returned to the calling function and the response is send to the client. But if an error occurs, I want to return the error to the calling function so I can send an error message to the client.

```
router.delete('/project', (req, res) => {
  return DeleteProject(userId, projectId)
    .then((response) => {
      //handle response
    });
});

DeleteProject: (userId, projectId) => {
  return deleteProject(userId, projectId)
    .then((response) => { 
      return response
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error in DeleteProject:', error) // This happens.
      return error; // this doesn't happen.
    })
},

function deleteProject(userId, projectId) {
  return Project.deleteOne( ... delete the project... )
    .then((response) => {
      return response
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return error
    })
}
```

The .catch(error) in the middle function above, DeleteProject(), gets triggered when an error occurs (ie, the console log happens), but the return doesn't make it's way back to the router.

How can I return the error to be handled by the router?

Comment: The most simple fix here is `return Project.deleteOne( ... delete the project... )` and do not chain this with `.then()` or `.catch()` ( which is really just `.then(null,<failfunction>)` anyway ) within your `deleteProject()` function. Let the actual things calling it deal with the promise and don't delegate. You actually did not mean to delegate, and probably didn't realize that was what you were doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply remove `catch` methods from the other two functions, and put the `catch` function in the router itself. Then the error will itself propagate to your router function

```
router.delete('/project', (req, res) => {
  return DeleteProject(userId, projectId)
    .then((response) => {
      //handle response
    }).catch(() => {
       // Add catch function here. Any error in "DeleteProject" and "deleteProject" will propagate to here
    })
});

DeleteProject: (userId, projectId) => {
  return deleteProject(userId, projectId)
    .then((response) => { 
      return response
    });
    // Remove catch function
},

function deleteProject(userId, projectId) {
  return Project.deleteOne( ... delete the project... )
    .then((response) => {
      return response
    });
    // Remove catch function
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To propagate errors through promise chains you need to throw them. In your `catch` handler, when you return the error rather than throwing it, you'e setting the (successfully) resolved value of the promise to be the error.

Comment: `Promise.reject()` could also be returned